# gdal_translate with input file list and output file list

Tags: linux, gdal

I used `gdal_translate -of ENVI inputpath1/RE1.tif outputpath1/RE1` in my linux shell for the conversion of one file. 
Now, I want do the same with 50 other files. Those files are in different subdirectories together with other tif files which I do not want to be converted and I have different output directories as well. So, I prepared two ascii files as input and output file lists:

input_list.txt:
inputpath1/RE1.tif
inputpath2/RE2.tif
inputpath3/RE3 tif

output_list.txt:
outputpath1/RE1
outputpath2/RE2
outputpath3/RE3

Is there a way to use `gdal_translate` like this: `gdal_translate -of ENVI input_list.txt output_list.txt`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could write a short program (in python, or perl, or bash, or your favorite language) that reads the input path, the output path, and then invokes gdal_translate. Something like this psuedo code:

```
input_paths = open(input_list.txt)
output_paths = open(output_list.txt)

while (input_paths.hasNextLine()) {
  current_input_path = input_paths.getNextLine()
  current_output_path = output_paths.getNextLine()
  system_call("gdal_translate -of ENVI " + current_input_path + " " + current_output_path)
}
```

*Actual code will vary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the translated files in the same directory, then this is easy. Say you have `input_list.txt` of path names to GeoTIFF files ending with `.tif`, and you need them as ENVI files ending with `.bsq`, this should work from a BASH shell:

```
while read f; do
    gdal_translate -of ENVI "$f" "`basename "$f" .tif`.bsq"
done < input_list.txt
```

Comment: But there is still another error in the code. If I run the code it gives me the error message:    *done < input_list.txtbasename: extra operand .tif
Try`basename --help for more information.
Too many command options.*    
However ``gdal_translate -of ENVI $f `basename $f .tif`.bsq`` without the while loop works fine.

Comment: I've added quotes to allow `basename` to understand paths to files that have spaces.

Comment: I think the error lies in the input_list.txt. The code is sensitive to line breaks and to a empty row in the end. Unfortunalely, I don't have time at the moment for puzzeling. :( So I just copied and pasted `gdal_translate -of ENVI input.tif output.bsq` with the data from my lists...